# What are .tflite files in React Native app bundles and how to remove them

Tags: react-native, google-play, expo

My mobile app is written in **React Native** and built using **Expo** as a bundle, then uploaded to **Google Play**.

Google Play Console warns me about size of the bundle and hints on removing largest files that are these:

- assets/models/fssd_100_8bit_gray_v1.tflite (2.49 MB)
- assets/models/fssd_100_8bit_v1.tflite (2.45 MB)
- assets/models/contours.tfl (1.16 MB)

Does anyone know what these files are and how to remove them from my app bundle? Google tells me that .tflite is for Tensor Flow Lite, but I am sure I am not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are Face Models used in Face Detection.

Comment: How does one remove it from your expo project if you are not using it? No one answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to eject to strip those models,

`expo eject`

Then navigate to `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
...
    // strip face detection from mlkit
    implementation (project(':react-native-camera')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.mlkit', module: 'face-detection'
    }
...
}
```

Or, if you don't want MLKit entirely just
edit `app/build.gradle`

```
 defaultConfig {
       ...
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

These files are for face detection and some gesture related function. These are generated as you are using react-native-camera. If you are not using these functions, You can unlink and uninstall the library and install and link again.

Remember in app/build.gradle use react-native-camera as general

defaultConfig {
        .........
        ........
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
       .........
       .........
    }

It is working for me, i think it will also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, those libraries were attached with `@react-native-firebase/ml`

Once I removed `@react-native-firebase/ml`, my final APK size reduced by **15MB**

[image]